# How to configure CsvHelper to skip MissingFieldFound rows

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

```
public interface ICsvProductReaderConfigurationFactory
{
    Configuration Build();
}

public class CsvProductReaderConfigurationFactory : ICsvProductReaderConfigurationFactory
{
    private readonly ClassMap<ProductDto> classMap;

    public CsvProductReaderConfigurationFactory(IProductDtoClassMapProvider classMapProvider)
    {
        classMap = classMapProvider.Get();
    }

    public Configuration Build()
    {
        var config = new Configuration
        {
            Delimiter = "\t",
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            IgnoreQuotes = true,
            MissingFieldFound = (rows, fieldIndex, readingContext) =>
                Log.Warn($"Missing Field Found at line {readingContext.Row}\r\n" +
                         $"Field at index {fieldIndex} does not exist\r\n" +
                         $"Raw record: {readingContext.RawRecord}"),
            BadDataFound = context => 
                Log.Warn($"Bad data found at row {context.Row}\r\n" +
                         $"Raw data: {context.RawRecord}")
        };

        config.RegisterClassMap(classMap);
        return config;
    }
}


public interface ICvsProductReader
{
    IEnumerable<ProductDto> GetAll(string filePath);
}

public class CvsProductReader : ICvsProductReader
{
    private readonly ICsvProductReaderConfigurationFactory csvProductReaderConfigurationFactory;

    public CvsProductReader(ICsvProductReaderConfigurationFactory csvProductReaderConfigurationFactory)
    {
        this.csvProductReaderConfigurationFactory = csvProductReaderConfigurationFactory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ProductDto> GetAll(string filePath)
    {
        var csvReaderConfiguration = csvProductReaderConfigurationFactory.Build();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, csvReaderConfiguration))
        {
            return csvReader.GetRecords<ProductDto>().ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

`MissingFieldFound` property is called when a missing field is found, but can not affect result.

I was wondering if it's possible to configure CsvHelper to skip rows with missing fields.

Comment: The docs of csvHelper have this. Just set it to null.

Comment: Could we have few more line of code? Perhaps the read part? Are you using `GetRecords` or `GetRecord` without s?

Comment: @user6144226, set to null `MissingFieldFound ` only off throws, not filtering result

Comment: @DragandDrop , I share rest of reader classes on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/u0wmssx7

Comment: I [edit]ed your question so the code is not on a external source. It's more clear now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is nothing wrong the way you did it, here is a mcve showing a complete exemple

```
var good = new List<Test>();
var bad = new List<string>();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    writer.WriteLine("FirstName,LastName");
    writer.WriteLine("\"Jon\"hn\"\",\"Doe\"");
    writer.WriteLine("\"JaneDoe\"");
    writer.WriteLine("\"Jane\",\"Doe\"");
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    var isRecordBad = false;

    csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = context =>
    {
        isRecordBad = true;
        bad.Add(context.RawRecord);
    };

    csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = (headerNames, index, context) =>
    {
        isRecordBad = true;
        bad.Add(context.RawRecord);
    };

    while (csv.Read())
    {
        var record = csv.GetRecord<Test>();
        if (!isRecordBad)
        {
            good.Add(record);
        }

        isRecordBad = false;
    }
}

good.Dump();
bad.Dump();
```

Comment: Your solution is working well in my case. 
But I do not see a way to copy your solution in in the form not violates the SRP.

Comment: @BanyRule It seems really hard to make it SOLID, sorry for the regression . `ShouldSkipRecord` could have Something that make it skip missing or bad data. For now `GetRecords` does not support this. You can make it a feature request : https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues.

Comment: This seems more like a workaround for when you read rows one by one yourself. For example in a case of using `CsvDataReader` and `SqlBulkCopy` you just provide reader instance to `SqlBulkCopy` (as it implements `IDataReader`) and don't handle reading yourself.

Comment: @LaurynasLazauskas, Sorry it's been years. I may need a little more context to understand. But you can use GetRecord**s** (with an S) and set `Configuration.BadDataFound`  and  `MissingFieldFound ` to null to have the default handling with no manual `csv.Read()`. There is no reason that missing fields row should be ignore, `Configuration.MissingFieldFound` allow you to set more complexe rules where you check what field is missing in order to know the approriate way you will handle: throws, insert in an other collection, err logging, etc

Comment: I am using `CsvHelper.CsvDataReader`. There is no `GetRecords` or `GetRecord`. This object is then passed down to `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync`. When there is a case of a missing field it still get read as a row with default values and fails. In this scenario I would like to be able to configure CsvHelper to skip rows in `MissingFieldFound`. But I guess this should rather be expressed in GitHub issues than here.

Comment: If you can formulate an [MRE] with a simple CSV, it's a valid question here too. But you should do both, both site use the same mark down so copy past and ad a link from gitbug to the respective SO question. I will advocate for SO as main question as it's rules allow better question that most of gitbug brain fart.

Comment: As of 20.0.0 this appears to have a breaking change 
"All CsvConfiguration properties changed to read only get; init;." ref:
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/

Comment: NOTE: this has an updated example for config  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916867/125981

Answer (score 9):

You can also configure missing fields using attribute

```
[Optional]
Public string Field {get; set;}
```

or

```
[Ignore]
public int Filed {get; set;}
```

Comment: It worked. Solved my problem by adding `[Optional]` attr. I'm using version 19.0.0.0

Comment: Where do you apply this attribute?

Comment: @KevinHudson on top of the property.  Just like the example above.

Comment: I formatted to make intent more clear but did not fix the Public vs public or any other change

Answer (score 8):

With the new version of csvhelper which I have (24.0.1) the below code will work to set `MissingFieldFound`

```
Dim textReader As TextReader = File.OpenText(filename)

Dim config = New CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        config.Delimiter = ","
        config.MissingFieldFound = Nothing
        config.TrimOptions = True
        config.HeaderValidated = Nothing

Dim csv = New CsvReader(textReader, config)
```

Comment: FYI for those searching the c# version of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73912748/125981

Answer (score 4):

Another way to skip `MissingFieldFound` rows is by using `ShouldSkipRecord` and comparing header record length to row record length.

```cs
// Load header record if you haven't already (CsvDataReader loads it automatically).
csv.Read();
csv.ReadHeader();

// Then do this.
var expectedRecordLength = csv.Context.HeaderRecord.Length;
csv.Configuration.ShouldSkipRecord = rowRecord => rowRecord.Length != expectedRecordLength;
```

This is particularly useful if you do not control the reading code (ex. when using `CsvDataReader` with `SqlBulkCopy`).

Answer (score 4):

Abumoosa's answer works for me except that was in VB. Here's the equivalent in csharp:

```
var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    
config.MissingFieldFound = null;

using (var reader = new StreamReader("taskList.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config)) {
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    while (csv.Read()){
       //get the record
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In later versions this setup would work since the `CSVReader.Configuration` properties are read only as of v 20.0.0.
So we move it to the constructor.

```
var config = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    MissingFieldFound = () => {}
}

using (var reader = new StreamReader("taskList.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config)) {
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    while (csv.Read()){
       //get the record
    }
```