# .Net Csvhelper header not found

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I have a class

```
 public class AccCsv
    {
       
        public string IdNumber { get; set; }
       
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
       
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
      
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to read these values from an excel document. My service for reading the doc looks like so

```
 public List<debtorCsv> GetAllDebtorImportedData(string path)
        {
            List<AccCsv> records;

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                records = csv.GetRecords<AccCsv>().ToList();
               
            }
            return records;
        }
```

However, when I run it I run into an error that says "Header with name IdNumber[0] was not found" (for all headers). I do have headers in my excel doc.
Does anyone who has used CSVhelper know what my error could be Thanks

Snap of my data: [sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdlWH.jpg)

Comment: Could you provide us an example of the data you're trying to convert so we can test it ourselves?

Comment: I have edited my question to include a snap of my data

Comment: CSVhelper can only read text files that contain Comma Separated Values.  So **not** Excel documents, unless you use Excel to explicitly save them in that format.  Google "c# read excel .docx file" to possibly get ahead.

Comment: Can you show the raw sample data instead of from Excel?

Comment: Thanks, I realized it was my data conversion from Excel that was not working properly. However, I am struggling to find a way to have some of the fields empty. I get a runtime error if it finds a header without a value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure CsvHelper to skip MissingFieldFound rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589868/how-to-configure-csvhelper-to-skip-missingfieldfound-rows)

Answer (score 2):

I found that similar issue may occur if you do not have a public, parameter-less constructor defined for your model class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply the decoration like this: `[Name("IdNumber")]` to your POCOS (as docs says : `https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/`) ?

something like:

```
 public class AccCsv
    {
     
        [Name("IdNumber")]  
        public string IdNumber { get; set; }
       
        [Name("Firstname")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
       
        [Name("Lastname")]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
      
        [Name("AccountNumber")]
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this thanks, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: even if you put index?

Comment: like:   [Index(0)]