CSVHelper Map available fields
Is there a way to map available fields coming from a CSV file ignoring fields that may not be present in the CSV? For example, I have a class with 5 properties. I want to allow mapping from CSV for matching fields ignoring non-matching or fields in the class that are not present in the CSV file.
class CsvRow {
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    public string Prop5 { get; set; }
}

CSV file:
Prop1,Prop3
P1,P3


this is probably the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67212436/14011696
[Optional]
Public string Field {get; set;}


This does work but it requires modifying the model which you may not have access to all the time. I assume that same can be accomplished via a mapping class?

in mapping class you can do Map(m => m.Date).Optional();
